# How to properly fetch the next rows in a database

Tags: sqlite, firemonkey, firedac, delphi-10.3-rio

I have tried using RecsSkip as found [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Fetching_Rows_(FireDAC)) however when I set RecsSkip it still grabs the first set of rows. I have tried using FetchNext which works for a little while. When I grab the second set it works then will not grab the third set.

First grab:

```
dmMain.Query.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM cards;';
dmMain.Query.Open();
```

Sequential grabs:

```
dmMain.Query.Disconnect();
dmMain.Query.FetchOptions.RecsSkip := skip * dmMain.Query.FetchOptions.RowsetSize;
dmMain.Query.Open();

and I have tried

//  dmMain.Query.FetchNext();
```

Comment: Not sure I understand clearly: You want to fetch rows from a SQLite database but skip the first rows and limit the number of returned rows? If this is what you are looking for, use LIMIT and OFFSET in your SELECT statement. See http://www.sqlite.org/draft/lang_select.html

Comment: want to grab the first set of rows, process data. when ready, grab the next set and process. repeat until done.

Comment: Thank You. Took some doing but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I transform my comment to an answer:

To get a block of rows from SQLite, use the [SELECT statement](http://www.sqlite.org/draft/lang_select.html) `LIMIT` clause with the `OFFSET`.

The `LIMIT` clause is used to place an upper bound on the number of rows returned by the entire SELECT statement.

Optional `OFFSET` clause that may follow a `LIMIT` clause. The first M rows are omitted from the result set returned by the [SELECT statement](http://www.sqlite.org/draft/lang_select.html) and the next N rows are returned, where M and N are the values that the `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` clauses evaluate to, respectively.